# Assigning styles with click event not working

Tags: javascript, html

this should be very simple. I want to assign `props` properties to all li's on click.

I start out with a for loop to iterate over all properties, nest another for loop to iterate over the collection of li's. This doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out what's wrong. I also get  the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

here is my code and a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v3Pdr/2/

html

```
<ul>
  <li>FooBar</li>
  <li>FooBar</li>
  <li>FooBar</li>
  <li>FooBar</li>
  <li>FooBar</li>
  <li>FooBar</li>
  <li>FooBar</li>
  <li>FooBar</li>
  <li>FooBar</li>
  <li>FooBar</li>
  <li>FooBar</li>
  <li>FooBar</li>
  <li>FooBar</li>
  <li>FooBar</li>
  <li>FooBar</li>
  <li>FooBar</li>
  <li>FooBar</li>
  <li>FooBar</li>
  <li>FooBar</li>
  <li>FooBar</li>
</ul>

<button type="submit">Click</button>
```

JS

```
(function(){

    var props = {
        color: "salmon",
        fontSize: "24px",
        textTransform: "uppercase"
    };

    for(var iterate in props) {
        for(var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll("ul li").length; i++) {
            document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
                document.querySelector("ul li").style[iterate] = props[iterate];    
                console.log(iterate);
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(document.querySelectorAll("ul li")); // has length of 20

}());
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You take the problem in wrong way:

```
(function(){

  var props = {
    color: "salmon",
    fontSize: "24px",
    textTransform: "uppercase"
    };

  document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
    for(var iterate in props) {
        for(var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll("ul li").length; i++) {
            document.querySelectorAll("ul li")[i].style[iterate]=props[iterate];
            };    
        }
    }

    console.log(document.querySelectorAll("ul li"));

}());
```

see [jsfiddle.net/v3Pdr/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/v3Pdr/3/).